# Refused to connect to [Any Url] because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-http

I am trying to access data within post method and its name is Login() but when URL is transfer to its location at that time Error is generated.

> Error:-Refused to connect to
>   'http://smartlearner.com/SmartLearner/UserAccount/LearnerLoginByMobileApp?Email=abc@gmail.com&Password=12345&crossDomain=true'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'".
>   Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is
>   used as a fallback.

I packed the "`Allow-Control-Allow-Origin`: *" extension and installed it into chrome but it does not work.

**Code**

```
 $scope.Login = function (callback) {
    $http({
        method: "Post",
        url: "http://smartlearner.com/SmartLearner/UserAccount/LearnerLoginByMobileApp",
        params: {
            Password: $('#Password').val(),
            Email: $('#Email').val(),
            crossDomain: true
        }
    }).success(function (data) {

        //Do Something here

    }, callback)
    .error(function (data, errorThrown) {

       //Do Something here

    }, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) to allow XHR support in your Cordova app. You can't make external requests without it.

Run: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git`

Comment: Of course! `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git`