# 404 error for an existing url calling from cordova app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

Here is my angular controller of a cordova app

```
angular.module('mobApp.controllers', ['ionic'])
.controller('SignupController', function($scope, $http, $location) {

        $scope.submitCommonSignUpForm = function(isValid, formData) {
            if (isValid) {
                var d = formData;
                $http.post('http://X.X.X.X/api/v1.0/basicSignup',formData).
                then(function(d){

                }).
                then(function(e){

                });
            }
        };  

});
```

I am getting `404` for `http://X.X.X.X/api/v1.0/basicSignup` but the fact is it exist. Any idea why ?

In my app Inside `platform > android > res > config.xml` i have`set <access origin="*" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the [whitelist plugin from Cordova](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

See my [previous answer regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32003040/2714730):

> You need to install the whitelist plugin to allow XHR support in your Cordova app. You can't make external requests without it.
>
> Run: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git`

Comment: but cordova has already added `<access origin="*" />` and the same is done through the plugin so what is the diff?

Comment: it worked but i am getting `Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' http://XXXXX.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.` in console why? i have set `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://XXXXX.com">`

Comment: @Manish, I'd possibly take a look at this as a starting point: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy. Particularly, "There is no mechanism for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, setting a script policy that includes 'unsafe-inline' will have no effect." Also, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060722/cordova-refuse-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-the-followi

Comment: Please, in future, vote to close posts as duplicates. Don't post what is basically a *see my answer elsewhere* post.