# Ionic Framework giving error while displaying json data

Tags: json, woocommerce, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Framework and WP-API to develop a mobile app for my Woocommerce based website.I am using the following URL to retriece JSON data about my products from the website -

http://example.com/wp-json/posts?type=product&?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK

When I try this URL from my browser, I get a perfect JSON response, with all the required details about my products. However, when i try calling the same URL through Ionic, the framework throughs an error.

UPDATE

```
$http.jsonp( postsApi ).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.posts = data;
      console.log( data );
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log( 'Post load error.' );
    });
```

Comment: Do you have the specific error message?

Comment: I am logging error to my console as follows
:console.log( 'Post load error.' );

Comment: Is the error a CORS error? If so, might be worth reading [Handling CORS issues in Ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/). I also notice you're requesting jsonp - is this intentional?

Comment: What is the error message ionic gives to you in the console, if you log the whole thing?

Comment: I have added the controller code at top.Please Check.

Comment: I am getting a 404 error

Comment: possible duplicate of [404 error for an existing url calling from cordova app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032270/404-error-for-an-existing-url-calling-from-cordova-app)

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a working link to try it again.

Try using service:

```
app = angular.module('appName', ['ionic']);

app.factory('postService', function($http){
  return {
    all: function all() {            
        var url = 'http://example.com/wp-json/posts?type=product&?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';
      return $http.jsonp(url, {cache: true})
      .success(function(data){
          return data;
      }).error(function() {
        alert("Error");    
      });
    }
   }
 });

app.controller("ItemController", function($scope,postService){

    $scope.item = [];

     postService.all().then(function(data){
        data = data.data;
        if(data.length == 0){
            console.log('empty return');
        }else{
            $scope.item = data;
        }
    });
});
```